# have postfix bounce all but procmail related non-delivery notification

Tags: postfix, email-bounces, procmail

Pardon me for reposting on serverfault; I mistakenly posted it originally on stackoverflow before, and was kindly reminded to post here.....

Problem: I experience every now and then non-delivery messages being sent out when procmail fails. Any non-delivery notification should go out but not those due to procmail errors.

Attempts without the expected

- main.cf: still bounces to external senders

  ```
  notify_classes = 2bounce, data, delay, resource, software, bounce
  bounce_notice_recipient = postmaster
  ```
- master.cf: no bounce messages at all

  ```
  bounce     unix  -       -       y       -       0       discard
  ```
- my procmailrc settings that seem to cause the error (but were working perfectly since the early 2000's until I upgraded to Debian 10 two months ago)

  ```
  VERBOSE=ON
  LOGABSTRACT=ALL
  PATH=/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin
  SERVER=`hostname`
  RECYEAR=`date +%Y`
  RECMONTH=`date +%Y%m`
  MAILDIR=$HOME/mail
  MAILDIRchk="`test -d $MAILDIR || mkdir -p $MAILDIR`"
  BACKUPDIR=$HOME/Backup
  BACKUPDIRchk="`test -d $BACKUPDIR || mkdir -p $BACKUPDIR`"
  BACKYEARDIR=$HOME/Backup/$RECYEAR
  BACKYEARDIRchk="`test -d $BACKYEARDIR || mkdir -p $BACKYEARDIR`"
  BACKUP=$BACKYEARDIR/$RECMONTH.backup
  LOGDIR=$HOME/MailLog/$RECYEAR
  LOGDIRchk="`test -d $LOGDIR || mkdir -p $LOGDIR`"
  LOGFILE=$LOGDIR/$RECMONTH.log.$SERVER
  ```
- The error message reported back to the sender :(

  ```
  <lpr_cxa@mail.destination.tld> (expanded from <my.name@destination.tld>): Command
      time limit exceeded: "procmail -a "$EXTENSION"". Command output: procmail:
      [44927] Mon May 18 15:48:12 2020 procmail: Assigning "LOGABSTRACT=ALL"
      procmail: Assigning "PATH=/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin" procmail: Executing
      "hostname" procmail: Assigning "SERVER=mail-vm" procmail: Executing
      "date,+%Y" procmail: Assigning "RECYEAR=2020" procmail: Executing
      "date,+%Y%m" procmail: Assigning "RECMONTH=202005" procmail: Assigning
      "MAILDIR=/home/lpr_cxa/mail" procmail: Executing "test -d $MAILDIR || mkdir
      -p $MAILDIR" procmail: Assigning "MAILDIRchk=" procmail: Assigning
      "BACKUPDIR=/home/lpr_cxa/Backup" procmail: Executing "test -d $BACKUPDIR ||
      mkdir -p $BACKUPDIR" procmail: Assigning "BACKUPDIRchk=" procmail:
      Assigning "BACKYEARDIR=/home/lpr_cxa/Backup/2020" procmail: Executing "test
      -d $BACKYEARDIR || mkdir -p $BACKYEARDIR" procmail: Assigning
      "BACKYEARDIRchk=" procmail: Assigning
      "BACKUP=/home/lpr_cxa/Backup/2020/202005.backup" procmail: Assigning
      "LOGDIR=/home/lpr_cxa/MailLog/2020" procmail: Executing "test -d $LOGDIR ||
      mkdir -p $LOGDIR" procmail: Assigning "LOGDIRchk=" procmail: Assigning
      "LOGFILE=/home/lpr_cxa/MailLog/2020/202005.log.mail-vm" procmail: Opening
      "/home/lpr_cxa/MailLog/2020/202005.log.mail-vm"
  Reporting-MTA: dns; mail.destination.tld
  ```

Question: Is there any configuration setting in postfix such that errors due to procmail failures are not reported -- but still all others are?

[[added]]

It seems that bogofilter suffers from a timeout

```
procmail: Executing "bogofilter,-uep"
procmail: [44927] Mon May 18 16:04:13 2020
procmail: Timeout, terminating "bogofilter"
procmail: [44927] Mon May 18 16:04:13 2020
procmail: Rescue of unfiltered data succeeded
procmail: [44967] Mon May 18 16:04:15 2020
procmail: Timeout, terminating "bogofilter"
procmail: [44967] Mon May 18 16:04:15 2020
procmail: Rescue of unfiltered data succeeded
procmail: Assigning "SPAMASSASIN=spamc"
procmail: Assigning "JUNK=Junk"
procmail: Assigning "LASTFOLDER=/home/lpr_cxa/Backup/2020/202005.backup"
procmail: Opening "/home/lpr_cxa/Backup/2020/202005.backup"
procmail: Acquiring kernel-lock
```

Comment: Your log output is incomplete; the actual error will be somewhere in the log file in the last line of the error message. Like I wrote in your original post, the sane solution is probably to fix your Procmail rules, but without seeing the logs around the failure, I can't say what's wrong.

Comment: Thank you for insisting!